# How to properly structure internal scripts in a Python project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythonpath

Consider the following Python project skeleton:

```
proj/
├── foo
│   └── __init__.py
├── README.md
└── scripts
    └── run.py
```

In this case `foo` holds the main project files, for example

```
# foo/__init__.py
class Foo():
    def run(self):
        print('Running...')
```

And `scripts` holds auxiliary scripts that need to import files from `foo`, which are then invoked via:

```
[~/proj]$ python scripts/run.py
```

There are two ways of importing `Foo` which both fail:

1. If a **relative** import is attempted `from ..foo import Foo` then the error is `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`
2. If an **absolute** import is attempted `from foo import Foo` then the error is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'`

My current workaround is to append the running path to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')

from foo import Foo
Foo().run()
```

But this feels like a hack, and has to be added to every new script in `scripts/`.

Is there a better way to structure scripts in such projects?

Comment: Is there a reason you do not put a `__init__.py` into `proj`, or `scripts` diretly into `foo` since they are all auxillary functions anyway?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's two ways you could resolve this.

### (1) Turn your project into an installable package

Add a `proj/setup.py` file with the following contents:

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="my-project",
    version="1.0.0",
    author="You",
    author_email="you@example.com",
    description="This is my project",
    packages=["foo"],
)
```

create a [virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html):

```sh
python3 -m venv virtualenv  # this creates a directory "virtualenv" in your project
source ./virtualenv/bin/activate  # this switches you into the new environment
python setup.py develop  # this places your "foo" package in the environment
```

inside the virtualenv, `foo` behaves as an installed package and is importable via `import foo`.

So you can use absolute imports in your scripts.

To make them run from anywhere, without needing to activate the virtualenv, you can then specify the path as a shebang.

In `scripts/run.py` (the first line is important):

```py
#!/path/to/proj/virtualenv/bin/python

import foo

print(foo.callfunc())
```

### (2) Make the scripts part of the `foo` package

Instead of a separate subdirectory `scripts`, make a subpackage. In `proj/foo/commands/run.py`:

```py
from .. import callfunc()

def main():
    print(callfunc())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then execute the script from the top-level `proj/` directory with:

```sh
python -m foo.commands.run
```

If you combine this with (1) and install your package, you can then run `python -m foo.commands.run` from anywhere.

Comment: While this solution does make the module available–in order for this to be callable as a typical script–one needs to add the script to setup.py using one of two argument options, as detailed in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Best practice? **Put a single entry-point in the root**

I know this might sound absurd, if you have lots of scripts you want to be able to execute... But it's actually the cleanest option and it's the one that is most often used in big Python projects like `magage.py` in Django, for example. It also doesn't need to be a huge undertaking. Even more importantly, it is *always* more secure to have a single entry point than several smaller ones.

```
proj/
├── run.py
├── foo
│   └── __init__.py
├── README.md
└── scripts
    └── my_script.py
```

When `run.py` lives in the root directory, it can be very lightweight... Basically just a wrapper to call the function you need from my_scripts.py. It just ties everything together so now all of your imports just work.

Just keep in mind that your entrypoint is your root. The parent of a root doesn't exist. So put your entrypoint in the root, and then import packages relative to the root, aka `import foo` from `scripts`.

**But how do I call multiple scripts!?**

If you need to be able to call multiple scripts, this is a good argument for... Well... [arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)! Keep `run.py` as your single entrypoint/command, and leverage subcommands to pass functionality to the script you care about.

**Reinventing the wheel?**

Generally, frameworks have already done the architecture for you to add your own subcommands, such as Django and, for a smaller footprint, [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/cli/).

You can easily wrap up a small project without that help, though, as I've illustrated.

**Security**

No one ever wishes their code was *less* refactorable after a few years of working with it. No one ever wishes their codebase has *less* security. As we drive to more secure systems in general, it would make sense to create some gatekeeper script that determines what is and isn’t a safe operation and by whom. Moving the code to an LDAP based system, and need to lock things down by group? No problem. You can either change the single file or add LDAP security in your codebase, even creating your own internal API.

With distributed scripts, security options are much less flexible and much harder to maintain, and a single vulnerability could leave you wide open to exploit.

**Bonus advantage**
You're adding abstraction to your script base. If you ever want to change the structure of your codebase (maybe you want `scripts` to have subfolders with more organization), you/your users don't need to do any refactoring for any dependencies, or change paths to longer, more verbose names. Your package is self-contained, and the only thing a user will ever need to touch is your `proj/run.py` entry-point.

And, obviously, you don't need to play with Python paths as much!

Comment: That's really a nice idea. I have multiple checkouts of different versions of my project to run various tests in parallel. Solutions like `pip setup -e .` works poorly in case because work only with a single version of a package.

Answer (score 6):

## Solution

There are multiple ways to achieve this. Both require creating a python package by adding a setup.py (building on @matejcik's answer).

**Option 1 (recommended):** `entry_point` + `console_scripts` register a function in your project as the entry point to script execution (ie: `proj:foo:cli:run`).

**Option 2: `scripts`:** Use this keyword argument in the `setup()` method to reference the path to your script (ie: `bin/script.py).

## Note

I recommend using a CLI library/framework like [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/master/) so that your codebase is only concerned with maintaining application specific business logic rather than CLI robust framework feature logic. Also, click recommends using `entry_point` + `console_scripts` method of script integration due to cross-platform compatibility.

Setup Tools - Automatic script creation: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation

Setup Tools - keyword arguments: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords

Click GitHub: https://github.com/pallets/click/

Click Setuptools integration: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/master/setuptools/

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `__init__.py` files to `scripts` and to `proj` folders for those to be considered Python packages and for you to be able to import from those.

One way this is also commonly done, is to place your `foo` and `scripts` folders into a `proj/src` folder, which then has a `__init__.py` file, and thus is a Python package.

Comment: That doens't really answer my question, adding an `__init__.py` to the top-level dir is bad taste, nor does it actually resolve the error. The class in the init file is just for simplicity in this example.

Comment: @YuvalAdam Yeah the comment about the class in the `__init__.py` was uwarranted, it' not terrible to have it there. But I stand by the fact that adding an `__init__.py` to the top-level directory is the way to go for sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you like simplicity, and there are no additional restrictions on what you asked, add one `__init__.py` to the `scripts` folder, and to any other sibling folders, making them packages, then always use the absolute import form, as you said you do not want `proj` as a parent package of those and so there is no `__init__.py` there,  and then call your scripts (instead) from inside the `proj` folder with:

`python -m scripts.run`

or whatever name you give to other scripts other than `run.py`

This is similar to option 2 of @matejcik answer, but even simpler.

Answer (score 1):

another solution is you add a.[pth](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) file on your Python directory

[image]

and write the content of the following,

```
# your.pth 

#↓ input the directory of proj
C:\...\proj
```

done

```
# scripts.py
from foo import Foo
Foo().run()
```

It will work well.

.. note:: If your IDE is [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), then you can use the [Source roots](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html) to help you too.

Answer (score 0):

Python looks for packages/modules in the directories listed in `sys.path`. There are several ways of ensuring that your directories of interest, in this case `proj`, is one of those directories:

1. Move your scripts to the `proj` directory. Python adds the directory containing the input script to `sys.path`.
2. Put the directory `proj` into the contents of the PYTHONPATH environment variable.
3. Make the module part of an installable package and install it, either in a virtual environment or not.
4. At run time, dynamically add the directory `proj` to `sys.path`.

**Option 1 is the most logical and requires no source changes.** If you are afraid that might break something, you can perhaps make `scripts` a symbolic link pointing back to `proj`?

If you are unwilling to do that, then ...

You may consider it a hack, but I would recommend that you *do* modify your scripts to update `sys.path` at runtime. But instead append an absolute path so that the scripts can be executed regardless of what the current directory is. In your case, directory `proj` is the parent directory of directory `scripts`, where the scripts reside, so:

```
import sys
import os.path

parent_directory = os.path.split(os.path.dirname(__file__))[0]
if parent_directory not in sys.path:
    #sys.path.insert(0, parent_directory) # the first entry is directory of the running script, so maybe insert after that at index 1
    sys.append(parent_directory)
```