# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.victim'; 'code' is not a package

Tags: python

I am trying to import a Python class from another file but it is not working. I've tried everything posted on relative imports but it is still not working.

My folder hierarchy is as follows:

[image: hierarchy]

I need to access the class Victim in victim.py file from test_db_debug.py file.

victim.py

```
class Victim:
    def __init__():
       ...
```

test_db_debug.py

```
import sqlite3
import sys
from code.victim import Victim
```

When i run the code, i get the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No Module names 'code.victim'; 'code' is not a package.

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Try with `from ..code import victim` or `from ..code.victim import Victim`

Comment: @CarloZanocco It gives the error ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent

Comment: Python version? Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57744466/how-to-properly-structure-internal-scripts-in-a-python-project)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's about naming conflict.

Try to rename "code" to something else.

Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36066463/479933